# Redis / Can I delete the all hash table?

Tags: node.js, redis

I use the following command in redis (with node.js):

```
// dbclient is the driver for redis in node.js
```

I set values by using `hset`:

```
dbclient.hset("all_cache", key, value);
```

and get it by using `hget`:

```
dbclient.hget("all_cache", "/" + key)
```

When I restart my application, I wish to delete all the records in `"all cache"`. Is there any way to do it with async command?

Answer (score 3):

To clear the hash, just delete the entire hash with `DEL`;

```
dbclient.del("all_cache")
```

A not very clean example (you should really use promises to sequence this instead of counting on redis executing async operations in order)

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value");

client.hget("hash key", "hashtest 1", redis.print)

client.del("hash key");

client.hget("hash key", "hashtest 1", redis.print)

> Reply: some value
> Reply: null
```

Comment: I did it, but when I use `dbclient.hget("all_cache", "/" + key)`, it still finds me keys from the old table.

Comment: @MiddleWare Seems to work here, added a runnable sample to the answer.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Sir, can we delete a single property in a hashset ?